# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property parameter of undefined

Tags: javascript, methods

So what I'm trying to do is create a class method that compares two objects and returns custom data depending on the results. To get this custom data, I have destructured parameters that *should* let me customize what kind of data it returns. Here's the code so far for reference:

```
    objects(obj1, obj2, { keysAndValues = true, returnSimplified = false, returnDetailed = false, keysOnly = false, valuesOnly = false }) {
        try {
            var results = [];
            if (keysOnly == true) {
                if (valuesOnly == true || keysAndValues == true) {
                    throw new SyntaxError('Two conflicting arguments cannot be chosen.');
                }
                Object.keys(obj1).forEach(o1 => Object.keys(obj2).forEach(o2 => {
                    if (o1 == o2) results.push(o1);
                }));
            } else if (valuesOnly == true) {
                if (keysOnly == true || keysAndValues == true) {
                    throw new SyntaxError('Two conflicting arguments cannot be chosen.');
                }
                Object.values(obj1).forEach(o1 => Object.values(obj2).forEach(o2 => {
                    if (o1 == o2) results.push(o1);
                }));
            } else if (keysAndValues == true) {
                if (valuesOnly == true || keysOnly == true) throw new SyntaxError('Two conflicting arguments cannot be chosen.');
                results.push('Keys: ')
                Object.keys(obj1).forEach(o1 => Object.keys(obj2).forEach(o2 => {
                    if (o1 == o2) results.push(o1);
                }));
                results.push('Values: ')
                Object.values(obj1).forEach(o1 => Object.values(obj2).forEach(o2 => {
                    if (o1 == o2) results.push(o1);
                }));
            } else if (returnSimplified == true && returnDetailed == true) throw new SyntaxError('Two conflicting arguments cannot be chosen.');

            var details = {
                NumberOfMatchingResults: results.length,
                ObjectName1: obj1,
                ObjectName2: obj2,
                ObjectKeys1: Object.keys(obj1),
                ObjectKeys2: Object.keys(obj2),
                ObjectValues1: Object.values(obj1),
                ObjectValues2: Object.values(obj2)
            };
            return ((returnSimplified == true && !returnDetailed == true) ? results.length : (returnDetailed == true) ? details : results);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
        }
    }
```

Now, it's not the prettiest piece of code out there, but for the most part, it gets the job done. The problem comes in when I try to call the method without one of the destructured parameters.
Example:

```
console.log(Compare.objects(obj1, obj2)); //returns 'Cannot read property "keysAndValues" of undefined'
```

I don't know what else to try, because nothing has worked so far, so I'm instead bringing the question here. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to set a default value for your destructured parameter itself. Just set its default value as an empty object to accomplish your desired outcome.

```
objects(obj1, obj2, {

   keysAndValues = true,
   returnSimplified = false,
   returnDetailed = false,
   keysOnly = false,
   valuesOnly = false } = {}

) {

// method code here

}
```

You can clean up your method further by eliminating equality operators when checking for truthy or falsey values. `if (valuesOnly)` is preferred over `if (valuesOnly == true)`.

Also, when comparing non-boolean values, you should always use strict equality operators to avoid bugs. So `(o1 == o2)` should be `(o1 === o2)`

Comment: Thank you! Most of this code I wrote at 4am last night so I know it's not the best, but yeah, this solves it!

Comment: No problem, been there before :)

Answer (score 1):

**Define your third parameter like this:**

```
objects(obj1, obj2, booleans = {}) {
  const {
    keysAndValues = true, // default value
    returnSimplified = false, // default value
    returnDetailed = false, // default value
    keysOnly = false, // default value
    valuesOnly = false, // default value
  } = booleans;

    ..... // block of code
}
```

**at the time of calling the method do this:**

```
// without third param
Compare.objects(obj1, obj2)

// with third param
Compare.objects(obj1, obj2, {
  keysAndValues : true, // or false
  returnSimplified : false, // or true
  returnDetailed : false, // or true
  keysOnly : false, // or true
  valuesOnly : false, // or true
});
```